# Using Callkit to make a call where phone number not known

Tags: swift, callkit

I am working on an app where I want to allow users to communicate by using a username and not to know the phone number.

I am not certain how to approach this, as it seems that [WebRTC](https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Getting-started-with-WebRTC-on-iOS/#Understanding-the-API) isn't the best choice, but I don't want to have the server send the phone number to the phone as that means that the user can potentially get the phone number if they break the encryption.

How do I make a phone call through Callkit and have it go through a server?  I expect to encrypt the packets so the server can't decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to provide the **Phone number** to the callkit. Just
  provide the display name while you receive the call, this is the way
  skype works.
- On tap of Recents history, your app will get redirected, from that you can make the call again. This method get fired,

  **- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity**

Comment: My problem is making the call.  I am wondering if I need to use WebRTC to initiate the call.

Answer (score 0):

You can trick call with Update action on Provider. See my Answer

[How to map social profile with CallKit API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957242/how-to-map-social-profile-with-callkit-api/41447244#41447244)